# Check if date column is in the range of last 3 months in Python

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, python-dateutil

Given a small dataset as follow:

```
   id        date
0   1  2020-01-01
1   2  2020-12-02
2   3  2020-09-26
3   4  2020-05-04
4   5  2020-01-05
```

I want to check if `date` is in the range of **3 months** from now (since today if `2020-12-25`, then the range will be `[2020-09-25, 2020-12-25]`), if not, then return new columns `check` with `N`.

The expected result will like:

```
   id        date check
0   1  2020-01-01     N
1   2  2020-12-02   NaN
2   3  2020-09-26   NaN
3   4  2020-05-04     N
4   5  2020-01-05     N
```

How could I do that in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution works:

```
import datetime 
import dateutil.relativedelta

start_date = (datetime.datetime.now() + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

mask = df['date'].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)
df.loc[~mask, 'check'] = 'N'
```

Out:

```
   id        date check
0   1  2020-01-01     N
1   2  2020-12-02   NaN
2   3  2020-09-26   NaN
3   4  2020-05-04     N
4   5  2020-01-05     N
```